# LWC - How to get label name of buttons

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have been trying to open a modal window onclick of a button menu. The modal will be child of the parent lwc and will be hidden. Its passed with some values

```
<lightning-button-menu class="slds-m-left_xx-small" variant="container" alternative-text="Show menu" icon-name="utility:settings" onselect={handleButtonselect}>
<lightning-menu-item value={topNewsItem.props.header} label="Email" prefix-icon-name="utility:email"></lightning-menu-item>
<lightning-menu-item value="Post" label="post" prefix-icon-name="utility:share_post"></lightning-menu-item>
<lightning-menu-item value="Task" label="task" prefix-icon-name="utility:task"></lightning-menu-item>
```

```
@track openEmail;

handleButtonselect(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('here >>'+event.detail.value);
    console.log('label >>'+event.detail);
    var menuValue = 'Email';
    switch(menuValue) {
        case "Email": this.openEmail = true; break;
        case "Post": this.post = true; break;
    }

}
```

In handleButtonselect how can i know whether email event has been selected or post or anything else. I am trying to create a custom component to email or post, when clicked. Is there a better way ?

Comment: why are you preventing the event propagation? what is the problem you are facing? event.detail.value should be returning the value of the selected menu item, the same would go for label or name attributes

Comment: I am trying to get what has triggered the select event through the label name. Unfortunately, as i understand, this event has only value parameter. Is there a way to get a label name in my handleButtonSelect

Comment: @glls `event.detail`only has `name` , interesting, I tried `this.template.querySelector` to get value, seems its more complex than it seems.

Comment: Looks like this same issue is there in [react](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1631) as well , which I think is mostly to do with ES6, i dont think this will be fixed sometime sooner.

Comment: @Pranay Jaiswal Other alternative is to out concatenated value in lightning-menu-item value={topNewsItem.props.header} +'$$Email' /> and retrieve the value. But not sure how this is done in LWC. The dom is generated at runtime with dynamic data. To concatenate i need to set it first in js and get the value. This is easily achievable if part of code in in child component and then child component renders to show the value.

Comment: You cannot concatenate in markup :( you have to concatenate in js nd use that value in markup

Comment: The markup is generated using topItems. I cannot call js function to concatenate without setting the value first, right ? How can get the concatenated value at the time of rendering of DOM in lightning-menu-item value= topNewsItem.props.header$$Email. I believe its only possible if the move the whole lightningButtonMenu markup as child and set the value of topNewsItem.props.header and then use its js to concatenate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Pranay , thanks. This is ok. But i need to have a custom value in lightning menuItems, so that on select i can get that custom value. The above is fine when we have static value.

```
<template for:each={topNewsServer} for:item="topNewsItem">
     <li key={topNewsItem.key} class="slds-item">
     <lightning-tile href="#" type="media">
     <c-account-title accounts-list={accounts} entity-id={topNewsItem.timeline} title-color={accountTitleColor}></c-account-title>
     <lightning-button-menu class="slds-m-xxx-small" variant="container" alternative-text="Show menu" icon-name="utility:settings" onselect={handleButtonselect}>
             <lightning-menu-item value={topNewsItem.props.url} label="Email" prefix-icon-name="utility:email"></lightning-menu-item>
             <lightning-menu-item value="Post" label="post" prefix-icon-name="utility:share_post"></lightning-menu-item>
             <lightning-menu-item value="Task" label="task" prefix-icon-name="utility:task"></lightning-menu-item>
     </lightning-button-menu>
     <p class="slds-truncate" title="">
         <span>
         <!-- passing property to child-->
             <c-relative-date-time epoch-date={topNewsItem.props.epoch}></c-relative-date-time>
          </span> via <span>{topNewsItem.props.domain}</span>
     </p>
     </lightning-tile>
     </li>
```

I need the value to be different so that onclick i can get the dynamic value and pass to modal or to childcomponent. I need to understand what i clicked in this case, whether email button or post or task.

Comment: I added code for same? On button click you get value, label and everything for that  `lightning-menu-item ` or am I missing something? can you edit your question to clarify instead of posting as an answer

Comment: Thanks Pranay. Your code helps. But i needed dynamic input values. I created a childcomponent just for menu buttons  and passed value from the parent and for each input text i appended the value with unique identifier.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [for:each](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lists) and declare the options as List of Objects in JS?

and then on `handleButtonselect` get the value and do an array search to get your label?

Html:

```
<template>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <lightning-button-menu class="slds-m-left_xx-small" variant="container" alternative-text="Show menu"
        icon-name="utility:settings" onselect={handleButtonselect}>

        <template for:each={optionsList} for:item="option">
            <lightning-menu-item key={option.value} value={option.value} label={option.label} prefix-icon-name={option.iconName}></lightning-menu-item>


        </template>
    </lightning-button-menu>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement , api } from 'lwc';

export default class SelectList extends LightningElement {

    @api optionsList = [{value : 'email' , label :'emailLabel' ,iconName : 'utility:email'} , {value : 'Post' , label :'postLabel' , iconName : 'utility:share_post'}];

    handleButtonselect (event){


        console.log(event.detail.value);

        let selectedValue = event.detail.value;
        let selectedObject  = this.optionsList.find(function(element){
                    return element.value === selectedValue;
        });

        console.log('selected Label ->' + selectedObject.label);

    }
}
```